# Mail client that can handle large mailboxes (thunderbird)

Tags: email, server, thunderbird

So i got thunderbird handeling all my mail. Have some extensions for copying and removing duplicated mails.

But now i got even larger mailboxes. They have about 100K mails with or without attachments.

And if i copy the mail from the server to the local folders i get the following message:

"The xxxx folder is full and can not contain any incoming messages. Delete old or unwanted mail and compact the folder to make room for more messages."

I thought this was an old message or a message if youre disk is formatted in fat32 (Can't handle files over 4gb)

So what limit am i reaching or what can i do to copy these folders from the server to the local folders.

I googled it but i keep going in cycles and can't find a solution.